# Running makefile by its name

Tags: makefile, mingw

I'm learning about `makefiles`. I've written a simple *hello world* like *makefile* named just *makefile2* but when I run `mingw32-make makefile2` I get:

`Nothing to be done for 'makefile2'`.

When I run just only `mingw32-make` (without supplying the file name) it works.

My question is it a rule to have only one *makefile* in the folder and to run it we don't provide a file name at all?

Is it possible to run specific makefile providing it's name?

PS. I'm using *MinGW* on *Windows 10*

Comment: You might find it useful to read the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Running.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html  This can often be faster than searching the web.  And you may learn things you didn't know to ask about yet :).

Answer (score 1):

Usually you need the -f option to tell make to use another file than Makefile or makefile, like

```
make -f makefile2
```

Without the -f flag, you tell make to build the target named (in your case) makefile2.

Comment: So when i type "make makefile2" without the "-f" option the make assumpts that i'd like to run the target named "makefile2" in the file (by default) named "makefile"?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. In my project I run a `make clean` if I want to tidy the source tree, a `make` if I want to build the software ("all" is the default target), a `make rpm` if I want to create rpm packages, and so on. This is why you only need a single Makefile most of the time